# Python Flask, BlueMix, js - Anonymous Function

Tags: python, flask, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, personality-insights

Using Flask and BlueMix to deploy a web app. Having some js issues that I cannot seem to figure out. I keep getting the same error in the browser console. I don't know any js so any help would be very appreciated!

```
jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4 POST http://newfla.mybluemix.net/ 405 (Method Not  Allowed)
send @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4
m.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4 
(anonymous function) @ demo.js:66
m.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3
```

Here is the supposed (anonymous function)

```
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    text: $content.val()
  },
  url: '/',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
    $loading.hide();

    if (response.error) {
      showError(response.error);
    } else {
      $results.show();
      showTraits(response);
      showTextSummary(response);
      showVizualization(response);
    }

  }
```

UPDATE:
I've tried a few different things matching your suggestions. Here is where I am now, any ideas?

```
consumer_token = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' #substitute values from twitter     website 
consumer_secret = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
access_token = '3473558363-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
access_secret = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_token,consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_secret)

api  = tweepy.API(auth)

class PersonalityInsightsService:
"""Wrapper on the Personality Insights service"""

def __init__(self, vcapServices):
"""
Construct an instance. Fetches service parameters from VCAP_SERVICES
runtime variable for Bluemix, or it defaults to local URLs.
"""


self.url = "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api"
self.username = "aaaaaa-vvvv-1111-2222-mmmmmmmm"
self.password = "password"

if vcapServices is not None:
    print("Parsing VCAP_SERVICES")
    services = json.loads(vcapServices)
    svcName = "personality_insights"
    if svcName in services:
        print("Personality Insights service found!")
        svc = services[svcName][0]["credentials"]
        self.url = svc["url"]
        self.username = svc["username"]
        self.password = svc["password"]
    else:
        print("ERROR: The Personality Insights service was not found")
def getProfile(self, text):
    """Returns the profile by doing a POST to /v2/profile with text"""

    if self.url is None:
        raise Exception("No Personality Insights service is bound to this app")
    response = requests.post(self.url + "/v2/profile",
                      auth=(self.username, self.password),
                      headers = {"content-type": "text/plain"},
                      data=text
                      )
    try:
        return json.loads(response.text)
    except:
        raise Exception("Error processing the request, HTTP: %d" % response.status_code)

class DemoService(object):
    """
    REST service/app. Since we just have 1 GET and 1 POST URLs,
    there is not even need to look at paths in the request.
    This class implements the handler API for cherrypy library.
    """

    screen_name = "realDonaldTrump"
    maxnumtweets= 500

    saveFile = open("static/public/text/en.txt",'a')
    saveFile.seek(0)
    saveFile.truncate()


    for status in     tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,id=screen_name).items(maxnumtweets): 
    print status.text[0:2] + '\n'
    saveFile = open("static/public/text/en.txt",'a')

    textyt = status.text

    texty = ''.join(i for i in textyt if ord(i)<128)
    saveFile.write(texty.encode('utf-8')+'\n'+'\n')
    saveFile.close()

def __init__(self, service):
    self.service = service
    self.defaultContent = None

    try:
        contentFile = open("static/public/text/en.txt", "r")
        self.defaultContent = contentFile.read()
    except Exception as e:
        print "ERROR: couldn't read text file: %s" % e
    finally:
        contentFile.close()

def GET(self):
   return render_template('newin.html', content= self.defaultContent)




def POST(self, text=None):
    """
    Send 'text' to the Personality Insights API
    and return the response.
    """
    try:
        profileJson = self.service.getProfile(text)
        return json.dumps(profileJson)
    except Exception as e:
        print "ERROR: %s" % e
        return str(e)


@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/getpost', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new():
    personalityInsights = PersonalityInsightsService(os.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES"))
c = DemoService(personalityInsights)
if request.method == 'GET':
    return c.GET()
elif request.method == 'POST':
    return c.POST()
```

Comment: seems like you are trying to use Personality Insights. Take a look at the python-sdk: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/personality_insights_v2.py

Comment: Thanks, German! I think the issue here is how unfamiliar I am with cherrypy. I was trying to convert this into a Flask based app, my issue being that I can't figure out how to initiate the POST.

Comment: take a look at this flash app that uses the text to speech service https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/text-to-speech-python

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a Javascript issue. The view function that is serving the root URL is not configured to accept `POST` requests. Response code 405 is `METHOD NOT ALLOWED` (the method here being `POST` as opposed to `GET`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, `OPTIONS`, `HEAD`, etc...

I'm able to recreate it with a very simple hello world Flask app

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Running the app from the command line (will be made available at `http://localhost:5000/`):

```
python app.py
```

and then trying to post against it from another terminal (using the `requests` library):

```
import requests

response = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/', data='')
```

print response will yield:

```
<Response [405]>
```

Note the `405` - the same response code you received, method not allowed. You need to explicitly define any methods other than `GET` that you want your Flask views to use by updating the `app.route` decorator:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World'
```

Generally however, you'll want to implement different functionality if a client does a `POST` instead of a `GET`. You can do this by looking at the `request.method` (you'll also need to import `request`):

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_world():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return 'You GOT hello world'
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        return 'You POSTed hello world'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

If you'd like to read more about the different HTTP methods, they are defined [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

Comment: *My comment is too long so kindly see second answer, thanks.*